# Trying to read RFID reader's response after writing a command to it, but getting an empty response

Tags: c#, multithreading, rfid

RFID name: YHY502CTG  13.56MHz RFID Mifare Read/Write Module

I am trying to write this command "AA BB 02 20 22" to RFID, in response to which i'll get

```
1) if no card is swiped == "AA BB 02 DF DD" .
Where "AA BB" == Head of this DATA , 
02 == Length of this DATA,
"DF" == One's complement of COMMAND,
02⊕DF(XOR) == "DD"

2) if there is card swipe == "AA BB 06 20 A0 8C 92 54 CC" 
where "AA BB" == Head of this DATA , 
06 == Length of this DATA, 
20 == COMMAND, 
"A0 8C 92 54" == Card Serial Number,  
06⊕20⊕A0⊕8C⊕92⊕54(XOR) == "CC".

CODE:-
byte[] bytesToSend = new byte[10] { 0x41, 0x41, 0x42, 0x42, 0x30, 0x32, 0x32, 0x30, 0x32, 0x32 };
_comport.Write(bytesToSend,0,10);// dont know whether ----correct way to write , but working properly//
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
var data1 = _comport.ReadExisting();//getting an empty response
MessageBox.Show(data1);
```

Comment: You might not be waiting long enough for a response. You can subscribe to the `SerialPort.DataReceived` event to make sure that you are getting data and waiting long enough for a response.

Comment: Hi @KDecker, I tried writing System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000); before reading using ReadExisting() , also i tried var data1 = "";
                while (data1.Length < 4)
                {
                    data1 = _comport.ReadExisting();
                } ---// but it goes into infinite loop , because the response is empty.

Comment: You need to hook into the `DataReceived` event itself and write an appropriate handler. Something like `RFIDDataReceivded += MySerialPortObj.DataReceived`. Then implement `RFIDDataReceived` and read the existing bytes/string in the buffer. // If this handler is not called you most likely have an issue with your connection to the device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the same problem. I assume you communicate with your reader via the serial port?

Try installing the [free serial analyzer](http://freeserialanalyzer.com/) tool, with this tool you can see what data is send and what is received to exclude coding mistakes.

Is there any Software shipped with the reader to get access to it? For me it helped first to connect and disconnect via the shipped software to my reader and after that I got responses from my reader when sending commands through my own code. Unfortunately I don't know why and I'm still looking for a better way.

Comment: Hello @croxy ,  I'm using Docklight V2.1 to see what data is send and received, the application is working properly with it.And also i didn't got any software with the reader.

Comment: Thank You @croxy, It helped, the free serial analyzer tool, was actually showing the data what i was trying to send . Previously i was using  Docklight V2.1 to see what is actually going to port , it was also working but the way this particular RFID wants the data was actually shown by the free serial analyzer tool. Thanks Again.. :)

Comment: @TapanTripathi Nice that I could help :)